# How does production database creation work in Jhipster?

Tags: java, spring, heroku, liquibase, jhipster

Having some issues when uploading my jhipster generated app to heroku, after some research I found out that some entity modifications I did while developing are not done in production db so some fields are missing.

I also added a field to User entity, so now I cannot even register/login while that field is missing from the table.

Would like to know how exacly the database generation works in prod mode so I can make it work. Could it be related to smth missing in liquibase changelog?(I'm absolutely new to liquibase so I'm a bit lost).

UPDATE:

The problem seems to be a missing column from "jhi_user" table. I need to create a database changelog to add that missing column, so I ran
    "mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog"

I saw the correct changelog poping in the console, but no changelog was created under my changelogs folder. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run `mvn install -Pprod` and `heroku deploy:jar target/*.war` again since running `jhipster:heroku`?

Comment: Yes, also tried to add the missing field for jhi_user  table to initial_schema.xml  but it still missing from production, i'm not sure if this is the proper place to add that extra column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was changelogs were not beeing generated when i created entities from yo jhipster:entity command.

Solved the issue doing:

```
mvn liquibase:diff
```

Plus some hand-done changesets and adding them to master.xml.

After that:

```
mvn liquibase:dropAll
mvn liquibase:update
```

Then deployed to heroku and every table was created.

Answer (score 2):

First, check that there is a migration file corresponding to your entity in the directory:

```
src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/
```

Then confirm that the Heroku app has a Database by running:

```
heroku addons
```

Then run Maven to repackage your WAR file:

```
mvn install -Pprod -DskipTests
```

Then deploy again:

```
heroku deploy:jar target/*.war
```

JHipster will run migrations at boot time. If you are using Postgresql, you can inspect the tables by running `heroku pg:psql` and using commands like `\d`

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. The problem seems to be related directly to the user entity, since i made some changes to the entity outside from the generator, so the new field that i added manually to the database in developments wasn´t at changelogs. I tried to add it but without success (question edited)

Comment: Did you edit the existing changelog? You'll need to create a new one because that one has already run.

Comment: Great so i need to create a changelog with smth like (comment updated)

Comment: "mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog" does not work as you think, please read [Liquibase doc](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html). Also in [JHipster doc](https://jhipster.github.io/development/) we give some hints on how to evolve entities and sync with Liquibase.

Comment: I`ve been looking around and cannot find a solution, done mvnw liquibase:diff to chek changes, added that changelog to master.xml and even created my own changelog for adding the colum my user entity is missing in production but still doing something wrong.